# Duvida rápida com Collate no MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

[image: Collate]
Eu defini o Collate como Latin_swedish_ci pra aceitar os caracteres com acentuação, mas como na segunda imagem, a data não é armazenada no formato português. Como fazer ela ser guardada em português? Isso é padrão pelo motor InnoDB e não dá pra mudar ou não tem nada haver?

[image: Data em inglês]

Comment: Resposta rápida: o collate define a codificação dos caracteres e não interfere de nenhum modo na formatação de data.

Comment: Mas e quando eu fizer as query terei que fazer o cast do formato ingles pro portugues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dados armazenados no Banco de Dados tem que estar num formato que guarde as informações necessárias sem ambiguidade, mas não tem que ter **relação nenhuma** com como a sua aplicação apresenta esses dados para o usuário.

Nesse caso, o `collate`  só diz para o banco de dados quais regras ele vai usar nas operações de ordenação - isso é `order by`. O formato que ele vai armazenar os dados internamente não deveria importar - dependendo do driver e da linguagem de programação pode fazer diferente, mas numa linguagem de alto-nível o driver vai te entregar o texto como unicode de qualquer forma.

Quanto as datas, esse formato não é o "inglês" - e sim um formato ISO para armazenar time-stamps (data e hora), que tem a vantagem de permitir a comparação de datas e horários caracter por caracter da esquerda pra direita, como se fosse uma comparação de strings normais.

O seu driver de banco de dados vai te entregar datas e time-stamps como um objeto de date ou datetime na linguagem de programação que você estiver usando, e aí vocẽ usa os recursos da linguagem para formatar essas datas e horários nas strings que quiser apresentar na interface --

Se estiver usando uma linguagem de relativamente baixo nível, em que as datas e horários venham como strings, a recomendação é usar alguma biblioteca auxiliar que tenha esses serviços de conversão de data pra você (em C por exemplo, existem as funções `stftime` e `strptime` da biblitoeca padrão).

## locale

Agora sim, na linguagem da sua aplicação (não no banco de dados), há uma configuração chamada `locale`, que integra com bancos de dados de localização para países específicos do sistema operacional.

O Locale sim pode ser configurado para poder formatar datas em formatos de países e línguas específicos, além de regras para o caracter que indica o ponto decimal em números, regras de ordenação (na aplicação, não no banco). 
Em geral é de médio pra difícil programar corretamente usando locale, dependendo da sua linguagem, mas dá pra usar funcionalidades específicas conforme as suas necessidades.

Comment: entendi, é padrão iso 8601 em qualquer banco de dados. O DateTime sempre vai ser YYYY/mm/DD HH/mm/SS independente da lingua atual sendo usada. As queryes serao feitas respeitando esse padrão, entao se eu informar na ordem diferente no caso pt-br DD/mm/YYY HH/mm/SS, vou ter que obrigatoriamente fazer o format. Os controles usados na tela do programa ja fazem o format desde que o locale esteja configurado na lingua desejada. No meu caso no c# é System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR")

Comment: As queries você deve fazer com objetos datetime da sua linguagem de programação - não com strings direto. O driver do banco de dados é que converte o seu datetime da linguagem para o do banco.

Comment: ahh sim, eu to fazendo a passagem de valores por parametros no formato do objeto do tipo datetime. Obrigado pelas dicas.